# PulseAudio removes sound from Ubuntu if it can't find a server

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, windows-10

I have two computers: A Windows 10 machine and a Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

I'm using PulseAudio on the Ubuntu machine to send sound to my PulseAudio server on Windows. This works great.

However, if the PulseAudio client on Ubuntu can't connect to the server, it removes the sound option completely, so if I want to hear sound directly from the machine (say to the speakers connected to it or the monitor), it doesn't work.

Basically, the sound icon in the top right doesn't even show up. I can move the volume slider but there's nothing attached to it. Only thing that's there is the Microphone volume slider icon. The Sound icon is blank/invisible.

How do I enable sound if PulseAudio can't connect to the **default-server** defined in **/etc/pulse/client.conf** ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

Backup /etc/pulse/client.conf

If I want to use local sound (speakers), remove /etc/pulse/client.conf and restart pulseaudio

If I want to use a remote server for sending sound to, copy the backup client.conf file back and restart pulseaudio